# stored hex values in notepad file with .ini extension how to read it in hex only via CAPL

Tags: capl

I have stored hex values in a text file with .ini extension along with address. But when i read it, it will not be in hex format it will be in character so is there any way to read value as hex and store it in byte in C language or in CAPL script?

Comment: if you know CAPL script then only answer this question as i know in other languages conversion function are there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you know how to read a text file in CAPL...

You can convert a hex string to a number using `strtol(char s[], long result&):long`. See the CAPL help (*CAPL Function Overview -> General -> strol*):

> The number base is
>
> - haxadecimal if the string starts with "0x"
> - octal if the string starts with "0"
> - decimal otherwise
>
> Whitespace (space or tabs) at the start of the staring are ignored.

Example:

```c
on start
{
    long number1, number2;

    strtol("0xFF", number1);
    strtol("-128", number2);

    write("number1 = %d", number1);
    write("number2 = %d", number2);
}
```

Output:

```
number1 = 255
number2 = -128
```

See also: `strtoll()`, `strtoul()`, `strtoull()`, `strtod()` and `atol()`

**Update:**

If the hex string does not start with "0x"...

```c
on message 0x200
{
  if (this.byte(0) == hextol("38"))
    write("byte(0) == 56");
}

long hextol(char s[])
{
  long res;
  char xs[8];

  strncpy(xs, "0x", elcount(xs)); // cpy "0x" to 'xs'
  strncat(xs, s, elcount(xs));    // cat 'xs' and 's'
  strtol(xs, res);                // convert to long

  return res;
}
```

Comment: if(this.byte(1)=='38' && this.byte(2)=='36') -----------------------   i want this comaprision and this.byte(1) contains 0x38 and this.byte(2) contains 0x36 can you provide solution to this problem.

Comment: @user1954578 Is '38' hexadecimal?

Comment: no 38 is string we retrived from .ini as character '3' and '8' and then we concantenate to get  string '38' so now we are comaring string '38' with 0x38 hex value

Comment: @user1954578 See the update. You can use `if (this.byte(2)==hextol("38") ...)`.