# Convert a string character to a hex value

Tags: vector, hex, capl, canoe

I´m trying to build a CAPL script in which I can read the string data contained in an array and then convert it to hex.
I tried to use functions such as "strtoul" and "DecodeString" but I couldn´t make it.
The code which I tried sto implement is the following:

```
    includes
{
  #include "Encoding.cin"
}

variables 
{
 char EcuInfoMFL[2][20] = {"0815","508"};
}

on key 'p'
{
  int i,j;
  long length, pos;
  dword Antw;
  char Antwort;
  
  for(i = 0;i<elcount(EcuInfoMFL);i++)
  {
    for(j = 0;j<elcount(EcuInfoMFL[i]);i++)
    {
      //length = strlen(EcuInfoMFL[i]);
      Antwort = strtoul(EcuInfoMFL[i],Antw);
      write("length: %X, Converted: %u", length, Antwort);
    }
  }
}
```

Any recommendations would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [stored hex values in notepad file with .ini extension how to read it in hex only via CAPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482972/stored-hex-values-in-notepad-file-with-ini-extension-how-to-read-it-in-hex-only)

Comment: Thank You very much for your answer, but in the case that you shared with me, a hex value is converted to a string, and what I need to do is to convert a string to a hex value. 
for example, I would like to convert "0815"  to hex values and this would be "30 38 31 35". This, in order to print it in the trace window like:
this.byte(0) = 0x30;
this.byte(1) = 0x38;
this.byte(2) = 0x31;
this.byte(3) = 0x35;

I hope this makes more clear my question... 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, you want to *convert* a string to its byte-representation, in order to be able to use it as (binary) content of a message.

In CAPL (same as in C, C++, or most other programming language) string are stored as a sequence of bytes.

So you can simply assign the characters to your message:

```
this.byte(0) = '0';
```

or in your case:

```
  for(i = 0;i<elcount(EcuInfoMFL);i++)
  {
    for(j = 0;j<elcount(EcuInfoMFL[i]);j++)
    {
      this.byte(j) = EcuInfoMFL[i][j];
    }
  }
```